# Dynamic facebook login button with Firebase on Android

Tags: android, facebook, firebase-authentication

Today I came across this problem;

I want to use the Facebook login button to sign users in to my app.

Now when the loginbutton is clicked, I log in, and continue to the 2nd activity.

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            // ...
        }
    });
```

Now in the 2nd activity I have a button "sign out" which returns me to the 1st activity, and sign out my account I have signed in with.

Code:

```
        AuthUI.getInstance()
                .signOut(this)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
```

Now, everything works fine, except for the sign out part.

It does sign out the account (I can see it in my log).

But when I get back to the MainActivity the dynamic Facebook login button still says: "Sign out" while it should already say: "sign in with Facebook".

This is the Facebook button I use:

```
    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

I have googled this, but I could not find anything.
Tried to change the sign out method to

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

But this was without any different result.

Comment: Nobody has any idea?

Comment: The answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985007/android-firebase-dynamic-facebook-button